# How can I invoke and use Google Cloud Functions in a Flutter app?

Tags: json, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I have created a url scraper function, working and tested on Google Cloud, but I am really drawing a blank on how to invoke it. I have tried two methods, one using the cloud_functions package, and the other using a standard HTTPS get. I've tried looking online, but none of the solutions/guides involve functions with an input from the Flutter app, and an output back to the app.

Here's the structure of the function (which is working alright). I've named this function Parse in Google Cloud Platform.

```
<PYTHON PACKAGE IMPORTS>

def Parser(url):
    <URL PARSE FUNCTIONS>
    return source, datetime, imageurl, keyword

def invoke_parse(request):
    request_json = request.get_json(silent=True)
    file = Parser(request_json['url'])
    return jsonify({
        "source": file[0],
        "datetime": file[1],
        "imageurl": file[2],
        "keyword": file[3],
    })
```

The first method I tried was using an HTTP CALL to get the function. But that isn't working, even though there are no errors - I suspect it's just returning nothing.

```
parser(String url) async{          // Here I honestly don't know where to use the url input within the function
    var uri = Uri.parse(<Function URL String>);
    HttpClient client;
    try {
      var request = await client.getUrl(uri);
      var response = await request.close();
      if (response.statusCode == HttpStatus.ok) {
        var json = await response.transform(utf8.decoder).join();
        Map data = jsonDecode(json) as Map;
        source = data['source'];            // These are the variables used in the main Flutter app
        postedAt = data['datetime'];
        _imageUrl = data['image'];
        keyword = data['keyword'];
      } else {
         print('Error running parse:\nHttp status ${response.statusCode}');
      }
    } catch (exception) {
      print('Failed invoking the parse function.');
    }
}
```

That didn't work, so I thought I might alternatively use the cloud_functions package as follows (in lieu of the previous):

```
  parser(String url) async {
    var functionUrl = <FUNCTION URL>;
    HttpsCallable callable = CloudFunctions.instance.getHttpsCallable(functionName: 'Parse')
      ..timeout = const Duration(seconds: 30);
    try {
      final HttpsCallableResult result = await callable.call(
          <String, dynamic>{
            'url': url,
          }
      );
      setState(() {
        source = result.data['source'];       //THESE ARE VARIABLES USED IN THE FLUTTER APP
        postedAt = result.data['datetime'];
        _imageUrl = result.data['image'];
        keyword = result.data['keyword'];
      });
    }
      on CloudFunctionsException catch (e) {
      print('caught firebase functions exception');
      print(e.code);
      print(e.message);
      print(e.details);
    } catch (e) {
      print('caught generic exception');
      print(e);
    }
    }
```

In the latter case, the code ran without errors but doesn't work. My flutter log states the following error:

```
I/flutter ( 2821): caught generic exception
I/flutter ( 2821): PlatformException(functionsError, Cloud function failed with exception., {code: NOT_FOUND, details: null, message: NOT_FOUND})
```

which I'm assuming is also an error at not being able to read the function.

Any help on how I should go about processing my function would be appreciated. Apologies if something is a really obvious solution, but I am not familiar as much with HTTP requests and cloud platforms.

Thanks and cheers.

Comment: What you define in your first snippet is a HTTP(S) function, not a Firebase-specific Callable Function. So your current approach of trying to invoke it as a Callable Function is not going to work. I see that you say "The first method I tried was using an HTTP CALL to get the function", but we'd need to see that code, and any relevant error/log messages to be able to help and debug.

Comment: That code is what I meant by being a call function. I suspect I might be using the terminology very incorrectly. I honestly can't fathom where the function call even happens in that snippet. Like how are the arguments passed at all?

Comment: Ah, I now see you have two client-side snippets. You might want to remove the one using `HttpsCallable` as it can't work anyway (as explained above). I'd remove all mention about `Callable` too to avoid confusion, and allow folks to focus on the minimum actual problem.

Comment: Actually, they are two different approaches I tried out to do the same thing, not in the same code. I have edited my question to reflect that change now, thanks.

Comment: I know they're two different tries, I'm trying to explain why the one using `HttpsCallable` can't work. I could also post it as an answer, and it would be a valid answer to your question. By explaining it in a comment, I'm trying to help you focus this question on the only case that **can** work, so that you don't have to post another question.

Comment: Oh, alright thanks. I had more confidence in that method tbh, since I was hoping to use a more direct approach, if available through the cloud_functions package.

Comment: Is there a way to make an approach using cloud_functions dependency work? Any edits I should carry out?

Answer (score 0):

Node Js Backend Function

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require("firebase-admin");
admin.initializeApp();
exports.test = functions.https.onCall(async (data, context) => {
  functions.logger.info("Hello logs: ", {structuredData: true});
  functions.logger.info( data.token, {structuredData: true});
}
```

Flutter frontend

1- pubspec.yaml

```
cloud_functions: ^1.1.2
```

2 - Code

```
HttpsCallable callable = FirebaseFunctions.instance.httpsCallable('test');
    final HttpsCallableResult results = await callable.call<Map>( {
      'token': token,
    });
```